# Cassandra stops during large inserts

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am inserting data in cassandra from a csv file using java driver.But after some inserts it throws **NoHostAvailableException:java 65 :All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried).**
I am having cassandra on client machine (singlenode).Cassandra services are still running on client machine.
Thanks in advance.I am a newbie.

Comment: @user3819405 Anything interesting from the server-side cassandra logs? Also how much memory have you given Cassandra / your app that is carrying out the inserts.

Comment: Do you execute one statement per row to insert, or use batch statements?

Comment: @OlivierMichallat Yes I also tried creating batch statement.But the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some best practices for bulk ingestions using the java driver:

http://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved by using executeasync method present in the java driver.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?